# No provider for Http! - migrating from angular 2 to 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have included `HttpModule` in my `import` as follows

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpModule, Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions } from '@angular/Http';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';
@NgModule({
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        .........
    ]
providers: [
        ApiService,
        .......
    ]
    })
```

ApiService is my custom Service .

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit,NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, AlertController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpModule, Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions } from '@angular/Http';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen, OneSignal, Network, CodePush, SyncStatus } from 'ionic-native';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { EventsPage } from '../pages/events/events'; 
import { NewsPage } from '../pages/news/news';
import { RadioPage } from '../pages/radio/radio';
import { GalleryPage } from '../pages/gallery/gallery';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
    declare var navigator: any;
    declare var Connection: any;

    @Component({
        templateUrl: 'app.html'

    })
    export class MyApp {

        rootPage = TabsPage;

        constructor(public platform: Platform, public alert: AlertController,
            private events: Events,
            public radioService: RadioPage,
            private codePush: CodePush,
            private ngZone: NgZone,
            public http:Http) { }

        ngOnInit() {

            this.platform.ready().then(() => {
                // My custom code
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u post your appcompone.ts file..and your import file for Http Module is **import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';**

Comment: @harish please check update

Comment: just write in your constructor  of your app.component.ts file `constructor(private http:Http)` importing like this `import { Http } from '@angular/http';`

Comment: @harish it didn't helped

Comment: can i have you are app.component.ts code full **what exactly is present in `imports` and `providers`**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146157/discussion-between-harish-and-webruster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use  `import { Response, Http } from '@angular/http';`in your component and service.

and as you posted above you are missing `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';`

**EDIT:**

Update your package.json to match the following dependencies, remove the existing node_modules directory, and then run npm instalL. Check this **[`link`](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2017-04-05)**.

Comment: actually i do have it in my code , while copying here i missed it

Comment: what about first line in your component and service?

Comment: component means in `app.component`    or `api.service` ?

Comment: app.component and api.service wherever you are using http

Comment: @sajeetjaran you can find my  `app.component` in the question and `api.service` here [api.service](https://pastebin.com/Xss7iEDr)

Comment: both looks fine according to me

Comment: yes !! for angular 2.4.0 this is a working code, for performance we migrated to 4 but got stuck here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146148/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-webruster).

Answer (score 2):

You should remove

```
providers: [Http]
```

from your component annotation.

And `'@angular/Http'` needs to be in lowercase, `'@angular/http'`

Comment: still no luck after removing

Comment: @Webruster where are you using `this.http..` inside your component? And you realize that `'@angular/Http'` has a typo right? It needs to be in lowercase

Comment: i havent using it anywhere in my component, one User asked to give a try with it so i added , all my api calling will be go from the api.service, you can check the code [here] (https://pastebin.com/Xss7iEDr)

Comment: it not typo actually, im trying to change with lowercase

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you missed importing HttpModule.

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: actually i do have it in my code , while copying here i missed it